# Want to understand panel var model fitting in r using pvargmm package

Tags: r, panel-data, gmm

Have multiple doubts here

1. How do I extract fitting values from model object?
2. How do I fetch each panel coefficient from it?
3. Prediction for the same?

Basically, I wanted to learn the working of this package for any panel sample dataset.

[image]

This is the sample dataset I am using where fac_id is the panel id and year is a time variable.

[image]

this is the model summary for lag 3 I got but these are fixed coefficient across all lags. Want to know the each panel id coef too and then prediction using same object

Basically, I wanted to learn the working of this package for any panel sample dataset.